# How to speed up maximization of the Solve output?

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization, symbolic

I am trying to maximize the solution of the system of algebraic equations for  different values of parameters. The problem is related to the absorbing times in Markov chains.

Here is the code

```
Kk=10; (*chain length*)
ra = {1.5, 0.5}; \[Mu] = 0.5; \[Gamma]ab = {x, y}; \[Gamma]ba = {1.0 - x, 1.0 - y};
 (* x and y here are variables that will be used in the maximization*)
```

Then I define the following lists, keeping `p1,p2,x,y` unspecified.

```
 \[Omega]ip = Table[\[Mu] ra[[k]] i/(ra[[k]] i + (Kk - i)) (Kk - i)/Kk + (1 - \[Mu]) \[Gamma]ab[[k]] i/Kk (Kk - i)/Kk, {k, 1, 2}, {i, 1, Kk - 1}];
 \[Omega]im = Table[\[Mu] (Kk - i)/(ra[[k]] i + (Kk - i)) i/Kk + (1 - \[Mu]) \[Gamma]ba[[k]] i/Kk (Kk - i)/Kk, {k, 1, 2}, {i, 1, Kk - 1}];
 \[Gamma] = \[Omega]im/\[Omega]ip;
```

The system of algebraic equations are

```
eqns = Join[Table[v[i + 1] == \[Gamma][[1, i]] v[i] + 1/(1 - p2 - p1) 1/\[Omega]ip[[1, i]] p1 Sum[v[j] - vv[j], {j, 1, i}] - 1/\[Omega]ip[[1, i]], {i, 1, Kk - 1}],
Table[vv[i + 1] == \[Gamma][[2, i]] vv[i] + 1/(1 - p2 - p1) 1/\[Omega]ip[[2, i]] p2 Sum[vv[j] - v[j], {j, 1, i}] - 1/\[Omega]ip[[2, i]], {i, 1, Kk - 1}],
 {Sum[v[i], {i, 1, Kk}] == 0}, {Sum[vv[i], {i, 1, Kk}] ==0}]
```

My goal is to maximize the unconditional absorbing time over `x` and `y` for given values of `p1` and `p2`.

To do so I define a function

```
G[\[Pi]1_?NumericQ, \[Pi]2_?NumericQ] := Block[{ sol, v, Vv},
sol = Solve[eqns /. {p1 :> \[Pi]1, p2 :> \[Pi]2}, Join[Table[v[i], {i, 1, Kk}], Table[vv[i], {i, 1, Kk}]]];  
v = First[v[1] /. sol];  Vv = First[vv[1] /. sol];
 NMaximize[{1/(1 - \[Pi]2 - \[Pi]1) ((1 - \[Pi]2) v - \[Pi]1 Vv), 0 <= x && x <= 1 && 0 <= y && y <= 1}, {x, y}]] ;
```

However, it is too slow. For `Kk=10` it takes 20 seconds for a pair of `\[Pi]1` and `[\Pi]2`.

I need to do for `Kk=100` and for 10000 pairs.

I tried to Solve `eqns` symbolically, and then insert the values of `\[Pi]1` and `\[Pi]2`. It works for smaller `Kk`, but for larger `Kk` it does not.

Any help would be highly appreciated.